# Combine two mysql tables and show the status of registered subjects and unregistered subjects

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. Enrolledsubjects table which contain subjects that students have been enrolled and stsubjects table which contain all the subjects that students need to be enrolled

### Table enrolledsubjects

```
c_id  |  Subject  |   Unit | Term  
 ----------------------------------
  1   |  English  |    3   | first
  2   |  Physics  |    2   | first
  3   |  Maths    |    3   | first
```

### Table stsubjects

```
s_id  |  Subject  |  Unit  | term
----------------------------------
 1    |  Chemistry | 4     | first
 4    |  Computer  | 3     | first
 5    |  English   | 3     | second
 6    |  Physics   | 5     | second
 7    | Mathematics| 3     | first
```

I am trying to join both tables where only the values not present in Enrolledsubjects table must be chosen from stsubjects. This is what I have tried so far..

This is the table am trying to get

```
## Expected Table ##

  id  |  Subject  |  Unit  | term | Status
--------------------------------------------
 1    |  Chemistry | 4     | first|  None
 4    |  Computer  | 3     | first|  None
 5    |  English   | 3     | second| Already Added
 6    |  Physics   | 5     | second| Already Added
 7    | Mathematics| 3     | first| Already Added
```

This is my PHP Code

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
     <table id="" class="table table-striped>
          <thead>
             <tr>
                <th>S/N</th>
                 <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
                  <th>Subject</th>
                   <th>Unit</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
     
            <tbody>
           <?php
            $count = 1;
             $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT c_id, subject, unit FROM 
               enrolledsubjects 
                   WHERE username ='".$getid."' AND term= '".$_GET['term']."' 
                   UNION 
                   (SELECT s_id, subject, unit FROM stsubjects WHERE term = 
                    '".$_GET['term']."' AND subject, unit
                  NOT IN
                   (SELECT c_id, subject, unit FROM enrolledsubjects WHERE 
                  username = '".$getid."' AND term = '".$_GET['term']."'))");
             
               $stmt->execute();
              $stmt->bind_result($c_id, $subject,$unit,$s_id);
              $result = $stmt->get_result();
               if($result->num_rows > 0){
                while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){
               $c_id = $rows['c_id'];
               $s_id = $rows['s_id'];
               $subject = $rows['subject'];
               $unit = $rows['unit'];
                   ?>
               

           <tbody>
               <?php 
                 if(isset($rows['c_id'])){
                    $status = "Already Added";
                      $select = '<td><input type="checkbox" 
                         name="checked_id[]" id="select_all" disabled 
                           CHECKED="CHECKED" value=""/>
                          ' . $rowc['c_id'].'</td>';
                        }else{ 
            $status = 'None';
            $select = '<td><input type="checkbox" name="checked_id[]" 
              id="select_all" value=""/>
                   ' . $rowc['s_id'].'</td>';
          }
          ?>
               <tr>
                 <td><?php echo $cnt;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $select;?></td>
               <td><?php echo $subject;?></td>
               <td><?php echo $unit;?></td>
              <td><?php echo $status;?></td>
            </tr>
               <?php 
                  $cnt++;
                       }}
                     ?>

                                    
                     </tbody>
              </table>
               </form>
```

I received mysqli syntax error.

Please I need your help

Comment: Homework? That is what it looks like.

Comment: Which database are you using - MySQL (`mysql` and `mysqli` tags) or SQL Server (`sql-server` tag)? And you need to post your full PHP code, not only the SQL statement. As an impotant note, do not concatenate strings and PHP variables to build a statement. Use parameters to prevent SQL injection issues.

Comment: I will update the post now

Comment: Learn to use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a `left join`:

```
select s.id, s.subject, s.unit, s.term,
       (case when es.subject is null then 'None' else 'Already added' end) as status
from stsubjects s left join
     enrolledsubjects es
     on es.subject = s.subject and es.c_id = ?;
```

Note that the `?` is a parameter placeholder for the student you are interested in.  Use parameters instead of munging query strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below way - you are missing an 'AND'

```
SELECT c_id, subject, unit FROM enrolledsubjects 
    WHERE username = '".$getid."' AND term = '".$_GET['term']."'
UNION 
SELECT s_id, subject, unit FROM stsubjects
   WHERE term = '".$_GET['term']."'
and subject NOT IN(SELECT subject enrolledsubjects 
   WHERE username = '".$getid."' AND term = '".$_GET['term']."')
```

Comment: Error in sql syntax.....I will post my full php code now